# tikz-qtree and tufte-book

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, linguistics, tufte, tikz-qtree

I want to use `tikz-qtree` to add trees to a book formatted with `tufte-book`. For the most part, they work. However, one example does not. Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
    \Tree [.mabubundok ma- [.bubundok \textsc{red} bundok ] ]
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, I get the following error message:

```
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
```

However, if I change the document class to `article`, it compiles just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
    \Tree [.mabubundok ma- [.bubundok \textsc{red} bundok ] ]
\end{document}
```

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for providing minimal example documents with your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with `tikz-qtree` but with the use of `\textsc` within the tree. The `tufte-book` class redefines `\textsc` using commands from the `soul` package. So you need to use `\textsmallcaps` instead.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
    \Tree [.mabubundok ma- [.bubundok \textsmallcaps{red} bundok ] ]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

You can see this clearly by comparing `\textsc` and `\textsmallcaps`. The former is letter spaced, while the latter is regular `\scshape`:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
\textsc{foo}

\textsmallcaps{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

This example provides a good argument for using semantic markup rather than formatting elements directly. So a better version of your code would be to define a macro for grammatical feature markup, which would then be defined as using `\scshape` directly, and only changed once in the document.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\feat}{\scshape}
\begin{document}
    \Tree [.mabubundok ma- [.bubundok \feat{red} bundok ] ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alan Munn. That solved it. Now where is the checkbox I'm supposed to check saying I accept this answer?

Comment: @dmort27 just below the voting buttons there is a faint green checkmark icon. Just click on that and it will display fully to mark the question as accepted.